# Angular 5 Event Emitter and Output does not reach parent function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, eventemitter

I have searched as much as possible and tried all the options on those questions to no avail. I have a button that should toggle a dark mode and so I'm sending a boolean value to the parent to change the background colour of the webpage. This is what I'm doing:

**Child**

This is the html file

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z5" color="primary">
<h1 class="first">firstName</h1><h1 class="second">SecondName</h1>
<button class="dark-mode" *ngIf="isLight" matTooltip="Bit too bright?" matTooltipPosition="before" (click)="changeMode()"><mat-icon>brightness_low</mat-icon></button>
<button class="light-mode" *ngIf="isDark" matTooltip="Bit too dark?" matTooltipPosition="before" (click)="changeMode()"><mat-icon>brightness_high</mat-icon></button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This is the .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'main',
 templateUrl: './main.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() isDarkMode = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  isLight: boolean;
  isDark: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isDark = false;
    this.isLight = true;
  }

  changeMode(){
    if(this.isDark) {
      this.isDarkMode.emit(false);
      this.isLight = true;
      this.isDark = false;
    } else {
      this.isDarkMode.emit(true);
      this.isLight = false;
      this.isDark = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Parent**

```
<main (isDarkMode)="isDarkMode($event)"></main>
```

This is the .ts file for the parent

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  isDarkMode(event: boolean) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my console.log statement is never displayed, I guess meaning that it's not event emitting the event?

Any help would be appreciated. I don't think I'm missing anything glaringly obvious...

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code into https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mackf4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Dakota I've added some simplified code to it now as I am using a lot of angular material. It doesn't seem to load but the main chunk of code is there. Are you able to see it?

Comment: Apologies, have updated the stackblitz. Here is the URL:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egkpzc
@Dakota

Comment: you should remove MainComponent in bootstrap:[AppComponent] , just keep only AppComponent , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gq7rsz

Comment: @Dakota Thank you so much!! Fixed it perfectly! A question, what is that bootstrap part for specifically?

Comment: You are welcome !. It's the root . Angular creates and inserts into the index.html host web page.

Answer (score 1):

In your child component, you need emit your event by calling changeMode(). You can emit your event when `changeMode()` is called by modifying your init function like so:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isDark = false;
    this.isLight = true;
    this.changeMode();
  }
```

You should see the console log then when `changeMode()` is called.

You said you have a button that should toggle a dark mode. In your html template:

```
<button (click)="changeMode()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Ahh sorry, did not include my child HTML. In the child HTML I have button showing what you had suggested at the bottom and every time I click the button, `changeMode()` is called but it never reaches the parent code and so I don't see the `console.log` output that I have in the parent .ts file

Comment: Strange...When you add a console.log to changeMode() in the child, do you see it firing there? If you have a repo I could poke at, I could take a quick look.

Comment: Hi Alex, it did fire correctly inside changeMode(). I have solved the issue now. In the comments to my original post ^. I had included all my files in bootstrap section in app.module.ts which was the problem! Thank you

Comment: Hi Alex, it did fire correctly inside changeMode(). I have solved the issue now. In the comments to my original post ^. I had included all my files in bootstrap section in app.module.ts which was the problem! Thank you